# Synonyms for "take risks/chance"

Tags: word-request

What are other similar phrases or vocabulary to express "take risks/chances"? In the following context:

> Some people believe that success in life comes from **taking risks or chances.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/risk?s=t
Using an online thesaurus you can find many different synonyms.
If you're ever unsure if one is used or not, just google the phrase and see.